# Can't set "WifiConfiguration" when enabling wifi-hotspot using "setWifiApEnabled"

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I'm trying to set my Android device to be an Access-Point using the code I've seen here before:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
netConfig.SSID = "MyAccessPoint";

Method method = wifi.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
method.invoke(wifi, netConfig, true);
```

now, I managed to turning it on but without the SSID which I set in WifiConfiguration.

This is driving me crazy.

Anyone?

Comment: I'm no expert on this but have you checked your manifest for the correct permissions ?

Comment: @Kerubu Yes, you are right, this might be the issue.

@FLEXpert Try adding `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` `CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE` and `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permissions in your manifest.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

Comment: I seem to remember having a few issues of this myself and vaguely remember reading that android fails silently if an app does not have the correct permissions hence programmers are left in the dark a bit!

Comment: ok, I finally managed to change the SSID but not on HTC phones

Comment: so how did you finally manage to change the SSID??

Answer (score 2):

Before Invoking the Method "setWifiApEnabled" you need to call "getWifiApConfiguration" to get the default WifiConfiguration 

Then change the SSID and Password and then invoke "setWifiApConfiguration" with the modified WifiConfiguration and after that call "setWifiApEnabled"

Here is the Code.

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

getWifiConfig = wifi.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration",null);
WifiConfiguration myConfig = (WifiConfiguration) getWifiConfig.invoke(wifi,null);

myConfig.SSID = "Hello World";

setWifiConfig = wifi.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApConfiguration",WifiConfiguration.class);
setWifiConfig.invoke(wifi,new Object[]{myConfig,true});

enableWifi = wifi.getClass().getMethod("setWifiEnabled",WifiConfiguration.class,boolean.class);
enableWifi.invoke(wifi,null,true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. One thing i observed during development. This doesn't work with the HTC devices.