# Can an Android device broadcast an SSID?

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, ssid, nintendo-ds

I want to look at data coming from a Nintendo 3DS on an Android device. The 3DS will automatically try and connect to any router with the SSID of "Nintendo_3DS_continuous_scan_000".

I know it should be possible, since tethering apps do essentially the same thing. I've tried looking at `Wifi Direct` or `Wifi P2P`, but so far I haven't seen any option to set an SSID. Am I looking at the wrong library for this project?

**EDIT:** I found a library [here](http://www.whitebyte.info/android/android-wifi-hotspot-manager-class) that handles the Access Points. I've successfully tested it once now, so I'm off to try crazy things.

Comment: i tried to follow your link but found nothing. Could you share us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the android device can be used as a hotspot it sure can. For changing the SSID you would use the `WifiManger` and `WifiConfiguration` classes. Their documentations can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#updateNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html) respectively. I also found a question I believe may help you with this. [Wifi Hotspot Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023226/android-2-2-wifi-hotspot-api?rq=1). And here is another question where the user was having trouble with HTC devices that might also be useful. [Hotspot Config on HTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823083/change-configuration-of-mobile-hotspot).

**EDIT** - My answer was assuming that you are trying to change the broadcast SSID of the device so that the Nintendo 3DS will connect to it, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your assumption was correct. Thanks for the references, that should get me started in the right direction!

Comment: Great, good luck. If you have any trouble just comment here and I can try and help.

Comment: OK, so I'm launched the code that's in the `Wifi Hotspot Configuration` link you gave, but it's not doing anything. I put in some debugging statements, and the `setWifiApEnabled()` method exists. No exceptions are thrown, but it doesn't generate the Access Point either. I have the permissions `INTERNET`, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`, and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`. Any idea what I'm forgetting?

Comment: It's hard to tell. There's not a lot of info about this, but I found a tutorial that is kind of old but may have some useful information. It lists some permissions you have to set in the manifest, [link here](http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/turn-off-turn-on-wifi-in-android-using.html).

Comment: And here is another question that seems to be relevant, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221712/cant-set-wificonfiguration-when-enabling-wifi-hotspot-using-setwifiapenabled). Sorry I don't know more about the topic, hope some of this will help.

Comment: Thanks again for the links. After some more digging around I got it working. Edited the original post with the library I used.