# Setup ad-hoc network programmatically

Tags: android, ios, networking

I'm doing some research about setting up ad-hoc network programmatically. And I would like to use Android or iOS to do that.

If there is no such api support that, I think it is possible to set up in lower level right (e.g. C)? Since I've already seen someone do that but it is for jailbroken iPhone.

http://intelliborn.com/mywi.html

I don't know much theory that how does ad-hoc work. I only have experience in socket and http network.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireless networking is a really big topic.  Your best bet is to start with the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html), refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337830/can-an-android-device-broadcast-an-ssid) and take a crack at it.

You may also find some clues in the source code for [android wifi tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/)