# Android lollipop hotspot programatically not working?

Tags: android, reflection, android-5.0-lollipop, access-point

I am trying to create hotspot programatically, unfortunately its not working in **android lollipop**.

For previous android version I was using "**setWifiApEnabled**" using reflection and it works fine.

I am struggling on this for a while now, any help would be great.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221712/cant-set-wificonfiguration-when-enabling-wifi-hotspot-using-setwifiapenabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after adding the permission :)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Any chance you can post more info?  I tried this solution, but it did NOT work for me, i get does not have permission CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL in the stacktrace.  I am on android 5.0.1

Comment: Did not work for me as well, running 5.1.1 on Samsung SM G920A (S6). Same permission issue "CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL", guess support has been removed for non-system apps?

Comment: @tushars do you mind giving us the model #, carrier, and os versions (e.g. SM-G920A, AT&T, 5.0.1/5.1.1) you found this working on? Maybe it is not working on certain lollipop devices

Comment: it was Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500 running on 5.0.1